# Rendering HTMLCalendar in django

Tags: python, django, calendar

I'm trying to get the calendar [here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2464/) working - but I cannot get anything returned to my index.html file other that `None`

Being new to django I may well be making a rudimentary mistake. I have the following in my views (Its en exact copy of the example code in the link really)

```
...
 55     my_next_month = my_month + 1
 56     if my_next_month == 13:
 57         my_next_year = my_year + 1
 58         my_next_month = 1
 59     my_year_after_this = my_year + 1
 60     my_year_before_this = my_year - 1
 61     return render(request, 'homepage/index.html', {'events_list': my_events,
 62                                                         'month': my_month,
 63                                                         'month_name': named_month(my_month),
 64                                                         'year': my_year,
 65                                                         'previous_month': my_previous_month,
 66                                                         'previous_month_name': named_month(my_previous_month),
 67                                                         'previous_year': my_previous_year,
 68                                                         'next_month': my_next_month,
 69                                                         'next_month_name': named_month(my_next_month),
 70                                                         'next_year': my_next_year,
 71                                                         'year_before_this': my_year_before_this,
 72                                                         'year_after_this': my_year_after_this
 73     })
 74 
 75 
 76 def index(request):
 77         users = User.objects.all()
 78         return render(request, 'homepage/index.html', {'users':users})
```

Can I even have the 2 `return render`'s in my views file? I want to render both objects (the calendar and a simple list of users) on the page. Users work fine.

In my urls.py file I have:

```
  4 urlpatterns = patterns('',
  5                 url(r'^$', views.index),
  6                 url(r'^$', views.calendar, name='calendar')
  7                 )
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks, Arthur

EDIT: Here's my template code. FYI - the variables all work just fine but the calendar returns None

```
  1 {% load staticfiles %}
  2 
  3 <!--The first few lines here pull in the dropdown banner--!>
  4 <title>Dashboard</title>
  5 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/banner.css' %}" />
  6 <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascript/banner.js' %}"></script>
  7 <script src="{% static 'javascript/jquery.js' %}"></script>
  8         <script>
  9         $(function(){
 10                 $("#includedContent").load("{% static 'html/banner.html' %}");
 11                 });
 12         </script>
 13 
 14         <div id="includedContent"></div>
 15         <!--End of dropdown barrier--!>
 16         <br>
 17         <br>
 18 
 19 {% if users %}
 20         {% for user in users %}
 21         <span>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</span><br>
 22         {% endfor %}
 23 {% else %}
 24         <b>no users</b>
 25 {% endif %}
 26 
 27 {% load event_tags %}
 28 
 29 <div id="calendar">
 30             {% event_calendar year month event_list %}
 31     </div>
 32 
 33     {% event_calendar year month event_list %}
 34     <br>
 35     {% for x in users %}
 36     {{ x }}
 37     {% endfor %}
 38     <br>
 39     {{ year }}
 40     {{ month }}
 41     <br>
 42     {{ events_list }}
```

Comment: you can have many `return render`s in your views file... one per view function.  you can't have the same url pattern pointing to two different view functions though, only one of them will ever work

Comment: what does your `index.html` template look like?

Comment: @Anentropic Thanks for the reply - I'll append it to the original post

Comment: ok, so the `event_calendar` tag needs to have `year`, `month` and `event_list` variables passed in from the view, but in your `index` view you currently only pass the `users` var to the `render` function.  do you actually want two separate views: `calendar` and `index`? or just a single page?

Comment: I've actually taken @Robin's advice and returned everything in index() - `def index(request):
        today = datetime.now()
        values = calendar(request, today.year, today.month)
        users = User.objects.all()
        values.update({'users':users})
        return render(request, 'homepage/index.html', values)` - still no calendar unfortunately

Comment: no that is wrong because `calendar` is a view so it returns an `HttpResponse` object.  Do you want two views?  If not then just move the code all into one view. If you need two views then I suggest move the code from `calendar` into a helper function that returns a dict that you can pass into `render` function, and call the helper function from both views

Comment: Could I nest the `calendar()` function inside `index()` or should I just have it all in the `index()` function and change any calls to `calendar()` to calls to `index()` ?

Comment: you shouldn't have a nested function, it sounds like you just want a single view so move the code from the body of the `calendar` view function into the body of your `index` view function

Comment: I finally got it working @Anentropic. I just stuffed everything into the `calendar()` view and changed the `urls.py` file to reflect that. It still wouldn't work but eventually it dawned on me that I needed an iterable object for `event_list` for the calendar to render - so I set it to `event_list = []`. Thanks a lot for all the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be on the same page, and rendered directly on the page, not through some ajax call with javascript you'll have to return them all in the same view.

```
 def index(request):
      users = User.objects.all()
      # Code for retrieving your events etc.
      return render(request, 'homepage/index.html', {'users':users, 'events_list':my_events, .....})
```

Currently, when you visit your base url, the first match in url pattenrs will be the one you receive, which is why users work, but not calendar.

You could modify your urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
               url(r'^$', views.index),
               url(r'^calendar/$', views.calendar, name='calendar')
               )
```

and visit your baseurl.com/calendar/ and see if it works. You cannot have two urls with the same pattern, tho.

Comment: Thanks - I got the data to display on the index.html page by calling a the calendar() function inside the index() function. Now if only I could get the calendar to render I'd be laughing!